# Dynamic dependant dropdown list in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, dropdown

**I have three Dynamic Dependant Dropdown Lists in Codeigniter:-**

1. One of them represents `company names`
2. According to the company I choose I want to show that particular company's managers on one of my other dropdown
3. The company's staffs are shown on my third dropdown.

Both manager and staff are saved in same column called `role_name` in `role_settings` table of database.

So far i proceed my code to get list of managers on dropdown, but when i run my code nothing happens, and I actually dont know how to get staff's list on my other dropdown. Here is my code.

**Project.php Controller:-**

```
<?php
class Project extends CI_controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // if(!$this->session->userdata('admin'))
    // redirect('admin');
     $this->load->model('project_model');
}

 function index ()
{
   
  $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getProjectDetails();
  $this->load->view('admin/project/index',$data);

}
function add()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Pname', 'Project Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Cname', 'Client Name' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('PassignTo', 'Company', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('manager', 'Manager' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('staff', 'Support Staff', 'required');
  
  $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();
  $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getProjectDetails();

  if ($this->form_validation->run() ==true)
  {
    $this->project_model->add(); 
    $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Added Sucessfully');
    redirect('admin/project/index',$data);
  }
  else{
    $this->load->view('admin/project/add',$data);
  }

}


function edit($id)
 {
   $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getById($id); 
   $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();

   $this->load->view('admin/project/edit', $data);

}
function update($id)
{
  $this->project_model->update($id); 
  $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project updated Sucessfully');
  redirect('admin/project/index');

}
function delete($id)
{
   $this->project_model->delete($id); 
   $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Deleted Sucessfully');
   redirect('admin/project/index');

}
function getAllManger()
{
  print_r($_REQUEST);
   die;
  if ($this->input->post('company_id'))
  {
    echo $this->project_model->
          getAllManger($this->input->post('company_id'));
  }
}

}
```

**Project_model.php Model Code:-**

```
<?php
class Project_model extends CI_Model
{
function getProjectDetails()
{
//table  (projects)
return $this->db->get('projects')->result();
}
function getById($id)
{
   return $this->db->get_where('projects',array('id'=>$id))->row();

}
function add()
{
    $arr['project_name'] = $this->input->post('Pname');
    $arr['client_name'] = $this->input->post('Cname');
    $arr['company'] = $this->input->post('PassignTo');
    $arr['project_manager'] = $this->input->post('manager');
    $arr['support_staff'] = $this->input->post('staff');
    $this->db->insert('projects',$arr);

}
 function update($id)
{
    $arr['project_name'] = $this->input->post('Cname');
    $arr['client_name'] = $this->input->post('regNo');
    $arr['company'] = $this->input->post('company');
    $arr['project_manager'] = $this->input->post('manager');
    $arr['support_staff'] = $this->input->post('staff');
    $this->db->update('projects',$arr);

}
function delete($id)
{
    $this->db->where(array('id'=>$id));
    $this->db->delete('projects');
}

function getAllCompanyName()
{
  $this->load->model('company_model');
  $this->company_model->getCompanyDetails(); 
  $this->db->order_by('company_name', 'ASC');
  $query = $this->db->get('company_details');

  //$query = $this->db->query('SELECT company_name FROM company_details');

   return $query->result();
}

function getAllManger($company_id)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$company_id);
    $this->db->oredr_by('role_name', 'ASC');
    $query = $this->db->get('roles_settings');
    $output = '<option value="">Select Mangaer</option>';
    foreach($query->result() as $row)
    {
        $output .= '<option value=" '.$row->manager_id.'">'.$row->project_manager. '</option>';
    }
    return $output;
}
function getAllStaff()
{

}
}
```

**add.php View**

```
    <?php
    $this->load->view('admin/header');
    ?>
     <div class="main-sec">
     <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <nav>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url ('admin/dashboard');?>">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo site_url ('admin/project');?>">Projects</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Add Projects</li>
            </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
       <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-primary float-right"  id="addProjects"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add Projects</button> -->
        <?php
        if($this->session->flashdata('success'))
        {
          ?>
                <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                   <?php
                echo $this->session->flashdata('success');
                ?>
                </div>
                <?php
                }?>
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="main-sec-contant">
           <div class="ProjectsAdd" >
        <h2 class="heading">Add Project</h2>
        <?php echo form_open('project_add'); ?>
        <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="text">Project Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Pname" placeholder="Name" name="Pname" value="<?php echo set_value('Pname'); ?>">
                  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Pname'); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="pwd">Client Name</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Cname" placeholder="Client Name" name="Cname" value="<?php echo set_value('Cname'); ?>">
                  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('Cname'); ?></div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="pwd">Project Assign To</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="company" name="PassignTo" value="<?php echo set_value('PassignTo'); ?>">
                  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('PassignTo'); ?></div>
                    <?php 
                    foreach($company_name as $row )
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->company_name.'</option>';
                    }
                   ?>
                  </select>

                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="pwd">Project Manager</label>
                  <select class="form-control" id="manager" name="manager" value="<?php echo set_value('manager'); ?>">
                    <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('manager'); ?></div>
                    <option value="">Select Mangaer</option>
                
                  </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                  <label for="pwd">Add Support Staff</label>
                  <select id="addStaffMulti" multiple="multiple" name="staff" value="<?php echo set_value('staff'); ?>">
                  <div class="alert-danger"><?php echo form_error('staff'); ?></div>
                    <option value="">Select Staff</option>    
                </select>
                </div>
           <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="btn-section float-right">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit" name="create" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Create</button>
               <a href="<?php echo site_url ('project');?>"> <button class="btn btn-danger float-right" id="cancelProjects" type="button" name="cancel" onClick="window.location.href=admin/project" ><i class="fa fa-plus-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Cancel</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
     </div>
 

        <?php
         $this->load->view('admin/footer');
         ?>
```

**JQUERY AJAX CODE:-**

```
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function()
  {
  $('#company').change(function(){
    var company_id = $('#company').val();
    if(company_id != '')
    {
      $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo  base_url();?>
             project/getAllManger",
        method:"POST",
        data:{company_id:company_id },
        success:function(data)
        {
          $('#manager').html(data);
          $('#addStaffMulti').html(' <option value="">Select Staff</option>');
        }

      });

    }
    else
    {
      $('#manager').html('<option value="">Select Mangaer</option>');
      $('#addStaffMulti').html('<option value="">Select Staff</option>');

    }
  });

  $()


  });
});
</
<script>
```

And image below is image of `role_settings` table in database, I am basically trying to display all `managers` from `role_name` column in my **Select Manager dropdown list** and display the rest of the `role_name` column datas on **Add stuff dropdown**.

[image]

Comment: could you please reduce all this code to the **essential**. [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Roxana Slj have your problem is solved or not?

Comment: yes solved , ill share the answer soon

Comment: @Roxana Slj Yes Please.

Comment: @KUMAR The answer is uploaded ,sorry for being late

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by making below changes in my code,also proceeded the form validation.
Project.php controller

```
<?php
class Project extends CI_controller
{
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // if(!$this->session->userdata('admin'))
    // redirect('admin');
     $this->load->model('project_model');
}

public function index ()
{
  $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();
  $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getProjectDetails();
  $this->load->view('admin/project/index',$data);

}
function add()
{
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Pname', 'Project Name', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('Cname', 'Client Name' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('PassignTo', 'Company', 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('manager', 'Manager' , 'required');
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('staff', 'Support Staff', 'required');
  
  $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();
  $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getProjectDetails();

  if ($this->form_validation->run() ==true)
  {
    $this->project_model->add(); 
    $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Added Sucessfully');
    redirect('admin/project/index',$data);
  }
  else{
    $this->load->view('admin/project/add',$data);
  }

}
function edit($id)
 {
   $data['project'] = $this->project_model->getById($id); 
   $data['company_name'] = $this->project_model->getAllCompanyName();

   $this->load->view('admin/project/edit', $data);

}
function update($id)
{
  $this->project_model->update($id); 
  $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project updated Sucessfully');
  redirect('admin/project/index');

}
function delete($id)
{
   $this->project_model->delete($id); 
   $this->session->set_flashdata ('success','Project Deleted Sucessfully');
   redirect('admin/project/index');

}
 public function getManager()
{
  //echo json_encode ("sdf"); die;
   //print_r($_REQUEST);
    //die;
  $company_name = $this->input->post('company_name');
  $getallmanager = $this->project_model->get_manager_query($company_name);
  $getallstaff = $this->project_model->get_all_staff($company_name);
  $all_the_mangers = '';
  $all_the_staffs = '';
  if(count($getallmanager)>0)
  {        
    foreach ($getallmanager as $manager){
      $all_the_mangers .='<option value="' .$manager->role.'">'.$manager->first_name.'</option>';
    }
    
  }
  if(count($getallstaff)>0)
  {        
    foreach ($getallstaff as $staff){
      $all_the_staffs .='<option value="' .$staff->role.'">'.$staff->first_name.'</option>';
    }
    
  }
  $result = array('manager'=>$all_the_mangers,'staffs'=>$all_the_staffs);
  echo json_encode($result);die;
  
}
```

}

And added below javaScript at the end of my project.php view .

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#company').on('change' , function() {
var company_name = $(this).val();
if(company_name == '')
{
  $('#manager').prop('disabled', true);
  $('#addStaffMulti').prop('disabled', true);

}
else
{
   $('#manager' ).prop('disabled', false);
   $('#addStaffMulti').prop('disabled', false);
  //var url = "<?php echo base_url()?>getManager";
  //alert(url);
  //return false;
   $.ajax({
     url:"<?php echo base_url()?>getManager",
     type: "POST",
     data: { 'company_name' : company_name},
     dataType:'json',
     success: function(data){
       //alert('ok');
       console.log(data);
       $('#manager').html(data.manager);
       $('#addStaffMulti').html(data.staffs);
       $('#addStaffMulti').multiselect('rebuild');
     },
     error: function(event){
       console.log(event);
       alert('Error occur...');
     }
   });
    }
  });
 });
 </script>
```